# Is this lemma equivalent to an extension being normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Definition: An algebraic field extension $M:K$ is normal if for all $a ∈ M$,
the minimal polynomial of $a$ splits in $K[x]$.

A reformulation of the definition is the following Lemma:  Let $M : K$ be an algebraic extension. Then $M : K$ is normal if and only if every irreducible polynomial over K either has no roots in M or splits in M.

Now my question is whether we can remove the word "irreducible" from the lemma. It seems like the proof still works because if the lemma applies to all polynomials, then it certainly applies to irreducible polynomials and minimal polynomials. Is that correct?

Comment: No, you cannot. The problem with including all polynomials is that by taking a product of an irreducible polynomial in $K$ which splits in $M$ and a polynomial over $K$ with no roots in $M$, you get a polynomial which only has some of its roots in $M$. For a concrete example, take $K = \mathbb{Q}, M = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Then $M$ is a normal extension of $K$, but the product $(X^{2}-2)(X^{2}+1)$ does not split in $M$, but it does have roots in $M$.

Comment: The correct equivalent statements you are looking for is/are this: $K/F$ is normal iff $K$ is the splitting field of *some* $f \in F[x]$ iff for every *irreducible* polynomial $f \in F[x]$ which has a root in K, $f$ splits completely in $K[x]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: consider $(x+1)(x^2-2)$ for the extension $\Bbb Q[i]:\Bbb Q$ (or even $\Bbb Q:\Bbb Q$), which has a root but doesn't split.

More generally, consider a field extension $M:K$ such that all non-zero polynomials $f\in K[x]$ have no roots in $M$ or split. Pick a purported non-constant polynomial $g\in K[x]$ without roots in $M$: by the defining property, $(x-1)g$ splits in $M[x]$, against the hypothesis that $g$ had no roots in $M$. Therefore your formulation is equivalent to $M$ extending an algebraic closure of $K$.

Comment: This is not a good example since for every $\;a\in\Bbb Q(i)\;$ it is true that its minimal polynomial over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ indeed splits in $\;\Bbb Q(i)\;$ ... In fact the condition in the question is equivalent to normality.